# WCF Exposing TCP Endpoints

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding, was

In terms of running endpoints that use the netTcpBinding, is my best option via IIS / enabling WAS?

Another option would be to host the TCP endpoints within a Windows Service.

Whats the big sell to utilise IIS/WAS for exposing TCP endpoints in WCF?

Cheers for any wisdom.

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosting TCP endpoints in a Windows Service or by using WAS which is part of IIS 7 is an example of managed hosting.

It really depends on whether you need managed hosting or prefer more control and want to "self host" your WCF service in a console app for example.

Here's a decent MSDN doc with some good info about hosting:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx